# Quantization Parameters when converting Quantized Transposed Convolution to Conv2D

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, generative-adversarial-networks, convolutional-layers, upsampling

A simple way to compute TransposedConv2d is to convert it to a regular Conv2d by padding the input value with zeros, as is described in [A guide to convolution arithmetic for deep
learning](https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.07285). Does this process affect the way quantization has to be handled?

In my case, with the hardware I am working with, this is done by changing the bias during code compilation and setting a scale factor. I am not sure if things like zero-point will affect the computation, especially since TensorFlow uses asymmetric quantization for inputs and outputs.